# Find multiple optimization parameters of Max-Min problem in numerically

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have an optimization problem 
$$\max \min [x_1,~\cdots,~x_m,~\cdots,~x_M]:~M\geq 2$$
where $$x_m=P_m(1-a_m)\prod_{j=1}^{m-1}\left(\frac{a_j}{1-a_j}+b_j\right)$$
and $$0\leq a_i<1;~~0\leq b_i<1;~P_m>0$$
Then, there are $2M-1$ number of parameters to be optimized ($a_1,\cdots,a_M,b_1,\cdots,b_{M-1}$). Actually, I can do this by using MATLAB, but I am wondering whether this kind of optimization can be done by using Mathematica using numerical techniques.

If anyone knows, please share with me. Thanks !!!

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried by using grid search ($a_i$ and $b_i$), but it does not give better accuracy as the solution depends on grid size, and also noticed that it is really difficult to extend it with more terms such as $M>3$, but the way I do in Matlab is much effective. I think that there should be better ways of doing in Mathematica but I am not that expert. So I am just wondering if any technique is available in Mathematica.